# SQL Server not respecting padding

Tags: sql-server, padding

When I save a string with blank spaces at the end, the string is being saved without the blank spaces.

In my development environment it works fine, but in production it doesn't.

Is there a configuration that can be done to force the blank spaces? It must be a configuration made via code.

Comment: Are these basic `VARCHAR` fields.

Comment: Blank spaces at the end are troublesome, because SQL has some weird rules for string comparisons (e.g. `abc` (no spaces) and `abc   ` (3 spaces) compare equal). Is there a very strong reason for needing to store such strings?

Comment: Yes, because it will be written into a predetermined txt layout file. But, I think I will manage this with other approach. I was just curious why SQL Server has this behaviour.

Comment: But it sounds like you're storing *formatting* in the database. It's usually best to store the *data* in its most natural representation and worry about formatting when you're actually retrieving the data (which in turn makes the system more flexible because if you ever need to support a second format, you don't spend half the time undoing the formatting that the second format doesn't want)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I will do this way! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As said by Damien, I will store data in its most natural representation and will format later.
Thanks!

Comment: Good - that's a best-practice. If you want to get to the bottom of why padding is treated differently on your different servers, do some research on the ANSI_PADDING setting.